# Why I cannot save my `_vimrc` after defining a register item?

Tags: vim

After adding the following definition of registrar, I can no longer save my `_vimrc`.

```
let @m = "V}k:s/ /\&/gV{j,tt$b${j$yV}k:s/\&kbkb&/ /kbkb/g"
```

Here goes the complete error picture. **As it turned out, my definition in `_vimrc` had not been precisely displayed on stackoverflow**. What I saw in the edit box goes to the very end of this post.

[image]

The editing box: [image]

Weirdly though, commenting it out also did no help! I still cannot save my `_vimrc`. Error message shall be the same.

Comment: From the error message in your screenshot, the error in your FocusLost Auto plugin preventing you from saving  `_vimrc`, try to disable or fix the FocusLost Auto first

Comment: It seems like you are trying to put non ascii characters in your file. Try setting the file encoding option appropriately (or change the characters to something vim understands)

Comment: @number5: the error message will occur whenever I try to save such buffer of `_vimrc`. FocusLost Auto will trigger a "save" action, thus the error message.

Comment: @FDinoff: I used `qm` to record the series of actions while I conduct a specific manipulation of texts. Then, I tried to assign these keystrokes to a register item permanently through the buggy definition I listed above. You are right that my encoding environment is `utf-8`, but this is for purpose of displaying Chinese characters. Would you suggest: 1. disable such specification of `utf-8`; 2. record the macro; 3. define the macro?

Answer (score 0):

The following setting in my `_vimrc` had caused the problem:

```
 set set encoding=utf-8
```

This setting is not evil by itself, but (I guess) it will lead to all the keystrokes typed through the keyboard encoded differently. `Vim` don't like it.

So, when I recorded the macro, while keeping such setting active, Vim was recording something that is only compatible with `utf-8`. Then, when I tried to assign what has been captured by the macro to a certain register item, `Vim` was confused about those weird keystrokes encoded "wrongly".

Solution in short:

1. Record the macro with `encoding` set as default (commenting out the existing encoding specification);
2. Paste from register to `_vimrc` and the definition shall be

   ```
   let @g = "{}{jV}k:s/ /\&/gV{j,tt$^M{j$yV}k:s/&//g^M"
   ```

Or, visually in `_vimrc` as follows: 
[image]

Comment: Your macro is not equivalent to the image. I would actually recommend changing `^M` to `\<cr>` or `\n`. vim will take care of converting them into the correct key code. You can also replace the `^Q` with `\<c-q>`. Read `:h expr-string` for all the ascii equivalents you can use. (Also make sure to escape you backslashes properly inside the double quotes)

Comment: @FDinoff, thank you for offering the idea of standardizing the expression. I have been using such register mapping too casually.

Comment: For the macro per se, the image is the correct version as it is directly from `_vimrc`. Such register item now work as intended. I guess it may due to some unknown encoding problems with either Firefox or my system register (clipboard), or both.